# Avoid having to repeat directory location in many places in XML

Tags: xml

I have an XML file with directory location mentioned at so many places. Something like the following;

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test>
  <LogFilePath>C:\Users\blabla\somedirectory\LogFile.txt</LogFilePath>
  <SettingFilePath>C:\Users\blabla\somedirectory\SettingFile.txt</SettingFilePath>
  <LogisticPath1>C:\Users\blabla\somedirectory\LogisticFile1.txt</LogisticPath1>
  <LogisticPath2>C:\Users\blabla\somedirectory\LogisticFile2.txt</LogisticPath2>
  <LogisticPath3>C:\Users\blabla\somedirectory\LogisticFile3.txt</LogisticPath3>
</Test>
```

As you can see the directory location is repeated multiple times. Is there a way to define it once and be able to use it everywhere?

Comment: Did I ask a wrong question or something? Why downvote without the explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a [DTD Entity](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_dtd_entities.asp) to represent the path.
The following example shows you an alternative to your original XML applying an *Entity*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE LOG [
<!ENTITY LOGPATH "C:\Users\blabla\somedirectory\">
]> 
<Test>
  <LogFilePath>&LOGPATH;LogFile.txt</LogFilePath>
  <SettingFilePath>&LOGPATH;SettingFile.txt</SettingFilePath>
  <LogisticPath1>&LOGPATH;LogisticFile1.txt</LogisticPath1>
  <LogisticPath2>&LOGPATH;LogisticFile2.txt</LogisticPath2>
  <LogisticPath3>&LOGPATH;LogisticFile3.txt</LogisticPath3>
</Test>
```

Comment: I could get a chance to test out the suggestion today and it worked great. Thank you again, its funny that someone even voted to close the post :(

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'm glad I could help.  I do not know the reason for the close-vote, but so far, there are no more CVs than this one, so everything should be fine.